# PowerBI Advenced Date Filtering

Tags: excel, powerbi

In my SQL DB I have a Created Date column which I would like to filter by in my PowerBI Report.

[image]

As you can see on the filter in PowerBI it does not filter by year/month/day as you can in Excel.

[image]

Can I make the PowerBI date filter show up as in Excel?

Comment: Are you sure your column is a date and not a varchar? When I recreate your problem using datetime the filters you require are present in PowerBI, when I change the type to varchar(19) I see the problem you describe.

Comment: 100% is a datetime field not varchar

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter in the page you can add filters by year, month and day with hierarchy or the hierarchy slicer (custom visual).

If you want the filter to be on advanced section (the one in your right) you have to add 3 columns corresponding to year, month and day.

Another approach is to check the preview feature "Show dates as a hierarchy (preview)"
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-january-2018-feature-summary/#dateHierarchy

With that you will be able to get that result.

The best practice in almost all power bi scenarios is to have your own date table

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't have the same visualization, but, if you want you can use advance filter:

[image]

With advance Filtering you can use calendar and hour as filter:

[image]

Comment: Yes I have found that option too. I just want an easier way for the less advanced users to be able to pick a date without going through so many menus. Is there a way to put the date picker on the charts page? As you could do it in SSRS

Comment: mmh i think is not possibile, but you can try to use custom visual : https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/show/Timeline1447991079100?WT.mc_id=Blog_Visuals

Answer (score 0):

When i deal with date column and for visualization purpose want to filter or add specific on axis or selector I always extract year, month and day from that column

Option 1:
Create new calculated table with formula `Date= CALENDARAUTO()` this would find all date column in your workspace and create date column with gathered dates

Then I create new calculated columns with

```
    Year= YEAR(Date[Date])
    Month= MONTH(Date[Date]) 
    Day= DAY(Date[Date])
```

Option 2:
You can always make those calculated column in selected table

I truly recommend first option because when then making a chart I just choose 'Date' table as axis (it works like a group, don't know how to name this) and there is no problem with format  and for your purpose with filter options

Answer (score 0):

You can  add columns of Year, Date and Day to the same table or to your calendar table and ADD this coluns at the filter page. This way you can provide the Year, Month and day visualization to users less experienced.